# How to run linux commands using cron

Tags: cron

I have a couple of linux commands I want to run everyday in the morning once using cron. Not sure how to do this though.

I understand that this needs to be done using shell, but I don't know how to do all this in linux. I will be able to create cron using cpanel though...

These are the commands

```
rm -rf <directory>
mkdir <directory>
chmod 777 <directory>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a shell script with this commands in a file script.sh, for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

rm -rf <directory>
mkdir <directory>
chmod 777 <directory>

<others commands or logical instructions>...
```

In linux you can add a cron job in crontab, with `crontab -e` command, or in `/etc/cron.d` directory. The difference is that with command crontab -e the cron job will be set to user that execute crontab -e and add a cron job file right in cron.d you will need to put the user ahead the command of cron job.

Examples of cron jobs to be executed at 06:00 am.

With crontab -e:

```
0 6 * * * /usr/bin/bash /path_to_script/script.sh
```

Creating a file in /etc/cron.d:

```
0 6 * * * root /usr/bin/bash /path_to_script/script.sh
```

Alternatively you can just put the commands in your cron job as:

```
0 6 * * * rm -rf <directory> && mkdir <directory> && chmod 777 <directory>
```

Attention: remember to put the absolute path to directories that want to remove or create

PS: you can make your scripts in any language and use shell calls, as php with `shell_exec()` function or `system()` function of perl.

Comment: I made this script and then I tried to run it via putty in commandline, "[$~] /home/username/public_html/script.sh " But I get a bad interpreter error. What is that and how do I solve it?

Comment: As it is a bad interpreter, it implies that path to your shell are wrong. Run 'echo SHELL', without quotes in command line to know if the path to your shell is informed correctly. The output, something like /usr/bin/bash or /bin/bash, etc; must be the shebang, the line with '#!/usr/bin/bash' in my sample above.

Comment: @SumitKumar Correcting: the command you should run is: 'echo $SHELL', without quotes. Since you need to know the path to your shell. If you already know that bash is your default shell, you can use 'which bash' command. Let me know if you can run your script in command line and tell about run it as a cron job.